# Adding a LinearLayout on top of Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to make a `VideoView` work on top of the cocos2d-x surface view. I am now able to load and play a video using the following snippets of code:

When Initializing the class:

```
// Create the LinearLayout that will contain our VideoView
_videoLayout = new LinearLayout( _activity );
_videoLayout.setId( VIDEO_VIEW_ID );
_videoLayout.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );
_videoLayout.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLACK );
_videoLayout.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );
_videoLayout.bringToFront();

// Add the LinearLayout to the current Activity
_activity = MyGame.getCocosActivity();
_activity.addContentView( _videoLayout, new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );
```

When playing a video:

```
// When the video is ready to be played, create a VideoView
VideoView videoView = new VideoView( Cocos2dxActivity.getContext() );
videoView.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ) );

// Add it to the _videoLayout object
LinearLayout layout = ( LinearLayout ) activity.findViewById( VIDEO_VIEW_ID );
layout.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
layout.addView( videoView );

// Play the video
videoView.setVideoURI( Uri.parse( path ) );
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

The above code yields the following results:

- The video is played and sounds are properly heard.
- The video is centered both horizontally and vertically.
- **Sometimes**, the video is played below the current Cocos2d-x view. Playing it again will make it be played on top of it.
- The video is not full screen. It only covers enough space in the screen to show the video.

What my expected results are:

- The video is played on top of the cocos2d-x view, at all times.
- The video takes up the whole screen, still maintaining aspect ratio, but has black borders on the sides.

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish these two. Any help? I'm not very experienced with the Android Framework so please bear with me.

**NOTE**: I don't want to use XML to create layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use XML layouts? They are designed for this, and amke your life much easier after you get a hang of them.

Anyhow : in my case I added my VideoView on a RelativeLayout and set its CenterHorizontal and CenterVertical parameters to true. The width and height is set to `wrap_content`. This was done in XML, so I cannot provide you with Java equivalent.

Also try calling `bringToFront()` on your layout to ensure that the video is on top of CocosView.

Comment: The cocos2d-x library does not use XML layouts. I'll try to use RelativeLayout instead and get back on this when I'm done.

Comment: True that. But it doesn't stop you from adding one :)